# How come Fedora ignores `module.sig_enforce` kernel parameter if SB is enabled but Arch does not?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules, secure-boot

I recently secure-booted Arch and Fedora on my RTX3050 equipped laptop.

As is the common knowledge, I had to sign my Nvidia modules on Fedora for the kernel to load them. However, I find that same is not the case with Arch. Arch loads the Nvidia modules even if they are not signed — provided, of course, that the kernel and the GRUB are signed.

Upon researching, I came across [this post](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Signed_kernel_modules) on the ArchWiki mentioning the `module.sig_enforce=1` kernel parameter to force signature verification. However, table 3 in [this entry of Fedora docs](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/f35/system-administrators-guide/kernel-module-driver-configuration/Working_with_Kernel_Modules/), mentions that the said kernel parameter doesn't make any difference when SecureBoot is enabled.

[image: table 3 from the attached Fedora docs link]

The [kernel docs](https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/module-signing.html) mention `CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_FORCE` option in the kernel configuration. So, I decided to take a look at Fedora's and Arch's configs.

And sure enough, [Arch](https://github.com/archlinux/svntogit-packages/blob/packages/linux/trunk/config#L877) doesn't have the option set. But, so doesn't [Fedora](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/kernel/blob/f35/f/kernel-x86_64-fedora.config#_3673).

So why this difference in handling of the modules?

EDIT: I found `CONFIG_LOCK_DOWN_IN_EFI_SECURE_BOOT` option that is present in Fedora's config but not in Arch's, after a chat in Fedora's Matrix Room. But, I cannot find any documentation related to this at [docs.kernel.org](https://docs.kernel.org); only a reference [here](https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20171020064315.GS3285@linux-l9pv.suse/T/). Is there a different site for documenting all kernel config options?

Comment: excellent question – I removed the filler text about people, because it wasn't contributing to the question (In case anyone gives you a hard time about using secure boot – it's what you, as the user, want. People being complicated about what is an understandable desire for common security features should not worry you! Ignore them.)

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you discovered, this is enforced by `CONFIG_LOCK_DOWN_IN_EFI_SECURE_BOOT`. That setting is supported by [a kernel patch](https://gitlab.com/cki-project/kernel-ark/-/commit/beab9fe7cef6739db1dcc56f0b3697b13c4eb4cd) which hasn’t been merged upstream; you’ll find it in Fedora and RHEL kernels but not in Arch.

Since it hasn’t been merged upstream, you won’t find it in the upstream kernel documentation, or on any other site which describes the upstream kernel.

Comment: but there's a plan to get this merged upstream, yes?

Comment: I imagine there is, but I don’t know for sure.